# html5 drag and drop returning wrong mime?

Tags: file, html, drag-and-drop

I have a HTML5 drag and drop file uploader, and it all works perfectly. However if I change say a .txt file to a .jpg file and upload it, the mime becomes image/jpeg, and the extension is .jpg.

How can I fix this, I need to make sure the user doesn't upload what ever as an image.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using PHP to check for JFIF,GIF89,PNG bom's and then using that to check for images. That seemed to be the only way possible.